# wordpress 3.8 do not have more button

Tags: read-more

i'm using latest version of wordpress and in editor i do not have more button to seperator content.

in source editor of that after inserting by hand or button of that in publish or update post, wordpress remove that and i can not seperator content.

Answer (score 1):

You can [add it back](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons#Enabling_hidden_MCE_buttons) or add the tag manually. http://codex.wordpress.org/Quicktags_API